# Custom SharePoint Responsive Master Page

Tags: sharepoint, office365, master-pages

We had a responsive html that was made responsive using bootstrap. Using Design manager i created a master page from it. Every thing works fine except 2 things.

1. Global Navigation doesn't match the UI, So i have applied all bootstrap classes using jQuery. Menu seems good later but at time of loading it looks bad.
2. When i go to add an app page, It shows only 4 apps. Search over there is not working as well as "Apps you can add" option is not visible on the page.

Can you provide exact steps that are to be followed in order to get it working fine?

Answer (score 1):

For the part of question related to global navigation what you can do it in two ways.

- Hide the global navigation using css first. Apply the bootstrap classes using jQuery and then show it on page to avoid loading effect.
- Try to pull global navigation data using REST and generate html and append it on page using jQuery. Try this link : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116393/get-links-from-sharepoint-2013-global-navigation-using-rest